# Avalonia UI XAML (AXAML) file doesn't work with Intellisense. How do I make it work like regular XAML?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, avaloniaui

I use Visual Studio to make my applications.  I installed the Avalonia UI extensions and I've started an Avalonia cross-platform application.  While trying to work with the XAML code, which comprises an AXAML file in Avalonia, I've been having trouble finding the properties that I need for the objects.  And I can't figure out why Visual Studio doesn't behave like it does for regular XAML files.

Here are two pictures taken one right after the other, the first for an Avalonia AXAML file, the second for a WPF XAML file.

[IntelliSense using AXAML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nk3qR.png)
[IntelliSense using XAML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dtzjn.png)

What you can see in the images is that AXAML seems to have problems finding the thing I'm looking for.  Stackpanel has a property "HorizonalAlignment" and "VerticalAlignment", both of which contain the word "align".  However, IntelliSense isn't filtering the properties at all.  It can't seem to get over the fact that my word doesn't start with the letter "a", and in fact most of the properties shown don't even have more than the first letter in commmon.

On the other hand, IntelliSense has no problem filtering the properties for the XAML file, as seen in the second image.  Using just "Align" on a Stackpanel, it brings up the only two properties that match.

So why?  Why does IntelliSense stop working just because it's an AXAML file when it works just fine otherwise?

I've tried searching around for explanations, but mostly the results talk about IntelliSense not working at all (which I don't think that is what is actually happening).  I've tried looking around in settings, but I can't find anything.  There's no reason why it should treat them differently.  It knows all of the properties available for the AXAML file, even the ones that aren't available in WPF.  So why can't it filter the list like usual?

Answer (score 0):

At Extensions try to install Avalonia for Visual Studio 2022.

Here is the link:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AvaloniaTeam.AvaloniaVS

Comment: I already installed this extension to Visual Studio.  The behavior you can see in the picture is the behavior with the extension.  Actually, playing around with it, the behavior is super glitchy, too.  For example, if I type in "allign" the first time, it will first skip down to the first item with an "a" in it, which is an event.  But everything else remains in the list.  There's no filtering.  If I erase the text, but don't leave the item, then type again, it DOES filter, but not well.  For example, it shows only events and control options, but still can't find "HorizontalAllignment".

Answer (score 0):

I just started following an Avalonia tutorial and also came across VS IntelliSense issue.

What fixed it for me was adding `xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views"` to XAML namespaces.

Comment: If I ever go back to Avalonia, I'll have to give that a try.  At this point, I've kind of moved on from making my application multi-platform.  I'm only using a web browser now.

Comment: As an Avalonia newbie I'd like to ask what made you abandon it, if you don't mind to share.

Comment: I found there were other features implemented in most other options, such as MAUI, that weren't implemented in Avalonia.  Some of them were really common ones, too.  It also had far more false errors than anything else I've worked with.  I could never tell which errors were real and which were false.  Their one beginner tutorial taught next to nothing, either.  The documentation is awful!  It's supposedly like version 11, but doesn't even have sufficient documentation.  Half of it said, "Go here to learn more" and there wasn't a page there.

Comment: Of course, there's also the problems that prompted this question in the first place, which were never resolved.  Why use something that doesn't work right, has no documentation, and lacks functionality I want?